# How do I receive input from a textbox in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, double, jtextcomponent, documentfilter

The following method extends a JFrame, but I need a swing textbox inside it to receive double values and store them in a variable. the textbox must be added to the container.

```
    public class myClass extends JFrame{
        Container container;
        container = getContentPane();

        //Item label
        JLabel labelText = new JLabel();        
       ...
        labelText.setText ("Item:");        
        container.add( labelText );

        //Item name: Textbox
        //code to make a textbox, add it to the container, and store the value in a                      variable goes here
```

Comment: You could look at [How to use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) and [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter), you could also have a look at [How to use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `JTextField`:

```
 JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
 container.add(field, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

To get the value of the field, do `Double.parseDouble(field.getText())`.