# Mac Jar Launcher does not wait for input

Tags: java, macos, jar

(First question so bear with me)

I'm new to java, and I'm trying to create an executable .jar file. I can run the .jar through the terminal, but when I double click the .jar in finder, it doesn't seem to want to open. When I check the console for errors, it looks like the program runs, but skips right over where I have user input and moves right through the code.

Here's the code that it skips over

```
private String readInputLine() {
    String line = "";

    System.out.println("\n>>");
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        line = reader.readLine(); 
    }

    catch(java.io.IOException exc) {
        System.out.println ("Read error: " + exc.getMessage());
    }
    return line;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!
If it matters, I'm on Snow Leopard 10.6.8.

Comment: I just made a class that makes it easy to enable double-click start for Java console applications, but this only works on Windows so far. It is prepared to support other systems, but I don't know the command line stuff. Maybe you can add the one line (or so) that's needed and make it work for you. If so, please tell me so that I can extend it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32547250/3500521

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to interact with the program by providing input, and you don't want the user to have to run the program through the command line like this:

```
java -jar /path/to/java/program.jar
```

If this is ok, then great! You can stop reading here. If you want to use a window then read on.

Then your best bet is to use a [`JTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) inside of a [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html). There are tons of tutorials on how to do this, one such tutorial (or question I guess) can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538127/how-do-i-receive-input-from-a-textbox-in-a-jframe) In addition to that here is an awesome [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) on how to use text areas in general. Hope that helps.